# Argument type inference in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type Inferred<T> = T extends (...args: (infer UnionType)[]) => any ? UnionType : never

function f(first: 'first', second: 'second', bool: boolean) {}

type T = Inferred<typeof f> // never
```

I expect the inferred type to be the union type `'first' | 'second' | boolean`.
I am aware that I can get it this way:

```
type Inferred<T> = T extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never

function f(first: 'first', second: 'second', bool: boolean) {}

type T = Inferred<typeof f>[number] // union type
```

or equivalently:

```
type Inferred<T> = T extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A[number] : never

function f(first: 'first', second: 'second', bool: boolean) {}

type T = Inferred<typeof f> // union type
```

Why does the first way not work?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, let's step back and see it from broader perspective.

TypeScript uses the same syntax (ie. `[]`) for both tuples and arrays. But they are sightly different concepts. I'll be using `()` (instead of standard TypeScript's `[]`) for tuples for brevity in the following paragraphs. Also, remember that `T[] === Array<T>` in TypeScript.

Tuples are - by convention - fixed-length and heterogeneous (holding values of possibly different types). `(1, "Adam", 42)` is a tuple of type `(number, string, number)` .

Arrays are usually homogeneous (holding value of the same type) and of arbitrary length.

In TypeScript, the difference between the two is slightly blurred because of union types support, ie. `[1, "Adam", 42]` is also a perfect `Array<T>` when `T = number | string`. This is not possible in languages without union types support (and would lead to finding lowest-upper bound of `number | string` which is usually something like `any`)

Using this knowledge in the provided example

`type Inferred<T> = T extends (...args: (infer UnionType)[]) => any ? UnionType : never`

we can see it as "get `T` out of function with arguments' list of type `Array<T>`.

We know that the type of arguments' list of:
`function f(first: 'first', second: 'second', bool: boolean)`
is `('first', 'second', boolean)`

At this point, a following unification (`:=:`) needs to be possible:

`('first', 'second', boolean) :=: Array<T>`

so that values of type `Array<T>` can be used wherever values of type `('first', 'second', boolean)` are used. And there is actually no such T, hence the inferred `never`.

It may seem like `T = string | boolean` or even `T = 'first' | 'second' | boolean` is a solution here but:

```
type Arr = Array<'first' | 'second' | boolean>
type Tuple = ['first', 'second', boolean]

const a: Arr =  ['first', 'second', true]
const t: Tuple =  ['first', 'second', true]

let a1: Arr = t;
let t1: Tuple = a; // Type error no. 2322
```

```
Target requires 3 element(s) but source may have fewer.(2322)
```

or on a type-level:

```
type TEA = Tuple extends Arr ? true : false // true
type AET = Arr extends Tuple ? true : false // false
```

It also explains why `type Y = Inferred<(a: number, b: number, c: number) => void>` yields `number`

To wrap up, `(infer UnionType)[]` in your example doesn't seem to support inferring tuple types but just arrays.

Disclaimer - I'm not familiar with TypeScript compiler internals and this is my best attempt to explain what happens here based on general knowledge and intuition.

Answer (score 0):

It's because a function of finite arguments cannot extend a function of (potentially) infinite arguments:

```js
// X is false
type X = 
    ((a: string, b: number) => any) extends ((...args: (string | number)[]) => any)
        ? true
        : false;
```

Your second two methods all use tuple types (`['first', 'second', boolean]`), which has a known finite length, which allows them to work.

Comment: It sounds convincing but doesn't seem to really hold up in TypeScript 4.1.2

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgjFAvFAFAQwFxQM7AE4CWAdgOYCUSAfFGkSANwBQoksATEqgHQ9p4nYsAQTx40IADy5CpShUTVaDRs3DQAwgAsIAYwDWCZPCgQAHsAhEAJtnZQA-FHwBXaFgBmaADbYI9KAD0AU54rqqsWrp6HEYcZhbWtsaOLm5Qnj5+gcGpQA